# Compare 2 Files using awk and print matching and non matching lines

Tags: awk

I have 2 CSV files with matching and non matching fields.
I want to compare second, third and fourth column and based on that want to have   output as matching(M), non-matching(NM) and also not found(NF with NULL) columns.

a) If col. 2,3 and 4 matches exactly then it is a match.
b) If col. 2 and 3 matches but not 4th then it should non-match.
c) If col. 2 or col 3 itself are non-matching then it should be a not found case.

### 1.csv

```
SL_2344,personal_details,name,Andrew  
SL_2344,personal_details,address,G-101 SSR New-Delhi  
SL_2344,personal_details,Age,22Y  
SL_2344,personal_details,sex,M  
SL_2344,personal_details,height,5.8 ft  
SL_2344,education,Roll_number,22345  
SL_2344,education,stream,ScienceandMaths  
SL_2344,class,section,3D
```

### 2.csv

```
SL_12332,personal_details,name,Samantha  
SL_12332,personal_details,address,Park Street Mumbai  
SL_12332,personal_details,Age,22Y  
SL_12332,personal_details,sex,F  
SL_12332,height,5.8 ft  
SL_12332,class,section,3D  
SL_12332,candidate_Other_details,sports,stateLevelBasketballrepresentation
```

### Output Desired

```
Class,Attributes,2344,12332,Remarks  
personal_details,name,Andrew,Samantha,NM  
personal_details,address,G-101 SSR New-Delhi,Park Street Mumbai,NM  
personal_details,Age,22Y,22Y,M  
personal_details,sex,M,F,NM  
personal_details,height,5.8 ft,NULL,NF  
education,Roll_number,22345,NULL,NF  
education,stream,ScienceandMaths,NULL,NF  
class,section,3D,3D,M  
NULL,height,NULL,5.3 ft,NF  
candidate_Other_details,NULL,sports,stateLevelBasketballrepresentation,NF
```

I have tried combination of awk associative array for $2,$3 and $4 using NR,FNR but not able to get the desired result.
Some records, as in 5th row, file 2.csv, only has attribute(and no class object) with value maintained in 3rd column where my code fails. NULL or Blank can be used for $2 for such records.

Comment: Please don't multi-post - [compare-2-files-using-awk-for-multiple-fields-and-process-result-for-matching-an](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636989/compare-2-files-using-awk-for-multiple-fields-and-process-result-for-matching-an)

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR { map[FNR]=$0;next } { split(map[FNR],map1,",");if ( $2==map1[2] && $3==map1[3] && $4==map1[4]) { print $0",M" } else if ( $2==map1[2] || $3==map1[3] && $4!=map1[4] ) { print $0",NM" } else { print $0",NF" } }' 1.csv 2.csv
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {                                                           # Set the field delimiter to ","
                   map[FNR]=$0;                                              # When processing the first file (NR==FNR), create an array map with the file number record as the index and the line as the value
                   next 
                 } 
                 { 
                   split(map[FNR],map1,",");                                  # For the second file, split the array entry into map1 using "," as the delimiter
                   if ( $2==map1[2] && $3==map1[3] && $4==map1[4]) { 
                      print $0",M"                                            # Print "M" entries based on the logic outlined utilising the split entries in map1.
                   } 
                   else if ( $2==map1[2] || $3==map1[3] && $4!=map1[4] ) {    # Print the "NM" entries based on the logic outlined
                      print $0",NM" 
                   } 
                   else { 
                      print $0",NF"                                           # Print the "NF" entries in all other cases.
                   } 
                  }' 1.csv 2.csv
```

Comment: Raman Thanks for trying this out but I get the below output when I run this -SL_12332,personal_details,name,Samantha,NF
SL_12332,personal_details,address,Park Street Mumbai,NF
SL_12332,personal_details,Age,22Y,NF
SL_12332,personal_details,sex,F,,NF
height,5.8 ft,,M
SL_12332,class,section,3D,NF
SL_12332,candidate_Other_details,sports,stateLevelBasketballrepresentation,NF
,NF
,,,M

Comment: What version of awk are you running? This works fine when tested locally with your test data.

Comment: GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: OK, I'm running 4.0.2

Comment: I see what the issue is. I'll take another look